# How many controllers(servlets) can be present in a java MVC web application?

Tags: model-view-controller, servlets

I am currently trying to develop one web application that follows MVC in java.I came to know that a well designed MVC web application should contain only one servlet which handles all user requests.Is it correct?Or can we have more than one i.e., several controllers(servlets) for handling different requests.For example in my application if I have following tasks and with different data base tables.
Submit an option
Get the details based on the selected option
present user details in one frame
display college details in another frame
etc.,
How many controllers(servlets) should be present in  MVC java webapplication?
Please suggest me.
Thank you.

Comment: As per your application requires.

Answer (score 0):

The original MVC only has one controller. But there are some enhancement patterns based on MCV, such as Hierarchical model–view–controller which has mutiple controllers. If your system is so complex, you could try to use the pattern. Anyway it depends on your system complex, and your preference.

FYI about HMVC

Hierarchical model–view–controller (HMVC) is a software architectural pattern, a variation of Model–view–controller (MVC) similar to Presentation-abstraction-control (PAC), that was published in 2000 in an article[1] in JavaWorld Magazine, the authors apparently unaware[2] of PAC which was published 13 years earlier.

The controller has some oversight. The controller selects the model and then selects the view, so there is an approval mechanism by the controller. The model prevents the view from accessing the data source directly.

Comment: So can I use more than one servlet for handling different requests?My web application has to present the data on browser when user clicks on a option.Based on that option I need to get the data from different data base tables and dispatches to jsp.So can I use different servlets?

Comment: I don't think you need multiple servlets, because your request looks not complicate. You could use mutiple DAO, and one service behind the servlet(controller) to implement your requirement.

Comment: Since I am having multile DAO's for multiple tables how can I get the details from multiple DAO's in a single servlet.Because In DAO's I am having methods for getting details.How can I call each DAO's method and how can return multile lists and dispatch to jsp.

Comment: You can use a service component which invokes all the DAOs, and then dispatch the result(In most desgin, it's a data bean) to a jsp page.